# how to destroy previews label when the function call again in tkinter python

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, software-design

```
def entering(a):


value=entry1.get() #entry1.get()is used to get values which entered in entry box



label1=Label(root, text =value, height=10) 
label1.pack()

entry1.delete(0, END) # used to clear entry box





root.bind('<Return>',entering)
```

how do I remove the widget that I created in the function call entering?
I know about the destroy function. I don't want to destroy it after a particular time.
I want to destroy it or overwrite it into the widget when I call the function again

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Comment: i just want to overwrite the label into the same place every time I call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you expect:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

myentry = tk.Entry(root)
myentry.pack()
var = tk.StringVar(root)
mylabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable= var)
mylabel.pack()

def entering(event):
    text = myentry.get()
    var.set(text)

myentry.bind('<Return>', entering)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no point to the `StringVar` here. Instead you could have used `mylabel.config(text=...)`.